# cannot get a particular table from a webpage, code use to work

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I had some code in excel vba that webscraped hundreds of pages by grabbing all the cells from a table called "Insider Transactions" on particular urls. The following is an example url: https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/HIL/insider

For some reason my code below no longer works. I cannot for the life of me work out why. The class I am trying to grab still seems to be called "normal-table data-table"

I have tried getting rid of the (0) as there appears to be only one table with the class name normal-table data-table now.

Set code is:

```
Set allCells = doc.body.getElementsByClassName("normal-table data-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
```

no error messages are given when I run my current code, but it is clear that allCells is not being set to anything because my code doesn't work and allCells.length doesn't return anything. Thanks

Comment: you are expecting to retrieve entire table?

Comment: what gets returned with `doc.body.getElementsByClassName("normal-table data-table")(0).innertext` ?

Comment: Are you doing any readystate listening?  Your code seems to work for me, but I do notice that there's a login pop-up that is loading a clear pane over the document and waiting for a user response.  I had to skip over my state check to read the document.  Maybe your credentials need to be supplied again to keep the pop-up from showing?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help you have led me to find my problem, I have been a doofus. It is not grabbing the table that is the problem it is the pressing of the button just to the top left of the table to get it to show 100/page instead of 10/page because this bit of the code wasn't working it thought their was no table. I do not know however why this section of the code has stopped working:

Comment: I will post a new question! because I can't still figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: solved it using QHarr's code .querySelector(".el-icon-caret-bottom"). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XMLHTTP:**

Faster than a browser and providing more info is xhr.

The data is provided from an API call. You can scrape the token for this and pass in a subsequent request. A few helper functions to get the token and handle results as well as a json parser to handle json response from API.

This requires installing code for jsonparser from [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) in a standard module called JsonConverter and then going VBE>Tools>References>Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim json As Object, headers(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long, results()
    Dim re As Object, r As Long, c As Long, dict As Object, p As String, token As String, s As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    p = "password_grant_custom\.client"":""(.*?)"""
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/HIL/insider", False
        .send
        token = GetToken(re, .responseText, p)
        If token = "Not found" Then Exit Sub
        .Open "GET", "https://www.gurufocus.com/reader/_api/stocks/NYSE:HIL/insider?page=1&per_page=1000&sort=date%7Cdesc", False
        .setRequestHeader "authorization", "Bearer " & token
        .send
        s = .responseText
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("data")
        headers = json(1).keys
        ReDim results(1 To json.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
        For Each dict In json
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
                If headers(i) <> "ownership_details" Then
                    results(r, c) = dict(headers(i))
                Else
                    results(r, c) = EmptyDict(dict(headers(i)))
                End If
                c = c + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function EmptyDict(ByVal dict As Object, Optional r As String, Optional key As Variant) As String
    Dim s As String
    For Each key In dict
        If TypeName(dict(key)) = "Dictionary" Then
            r = EmptyDict(dict(key), r, key)
        Else
            s = IIf(key = "D", "Direct ", key)
            r = r & s & " " & dict(key) & Chr$(10)
        End If
    Next
    EmptyDict = r
End Function

Public Function GetToken(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then               ' returns True if the regex pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
            GetToken = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetToken = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

---

**Using browser and also setting results to 100 per page:**

The following dimisses login message if present.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/HIL/insider"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            If .querySelectorAll(".login-card").Length > 0 Then
                .querySelector(".login-card .el-icon-close").Click
            End If
            .querySelector(".el-icon-caret-bottom").Click
            .querySelector(".aio-popover-item:nth-of-type(6)").Click
        End With
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        clipboard.SetText .document.querySelector(".data-table").outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let data = document.body.getElementsByClassName("normal-table data-table")[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
  // do something with data
})
```

Instead of the round **'('** brackets, it seems fine. But, it could be possible that the data in table is loading after your function runs, so its throwing error.

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905183/how-do-you-get-elements-from-a-javascript-htmlcollection)

Comment: this looks like javascript or something else?  OP is working in VBA.