# Excel VBA Web Scraping Table Elements from a <frameset> and a <frame>

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some table-looking items from a website into Excel.

I'm no stranger to coding in general, though I'm pretty new to VBA in an Excel sense :)

I have tried using Excel's Data>From Web interface, it's not recognizing the table. I'm guessing it's because it's built using  (or at least that's what my Google-Fu has lead me to understand).

[Snipping of what the second table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mtV8.png)

```
<html>

<frame title="links" ...>...</frame>

<frame title="queue">
#document

<head>...</head>
<body>
<div id="container>
<script>...</script>
<div>

<table id="oTable">

<colgroup>...</colgroup>

<thead>...</thead>


<tbody>
  <tr onclick="changeHighlight( 'eid0' )" id="eid0" class="queryshaded">
    <td nowrap=""><a onclick="javascript:window.open('IWViewer.jsp?id=3.5599976.5599976');" title="Open Image" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Image" border="0" alt="Open Image" src="URL.gif"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('URL','_newtab');" title="Open Workitem" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Workitem" border="0" alt="Open Workitem" src="URL.gif"></a>
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">12345</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="`" target="_Blank">28/08/2018 17:00:49</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">11/09/2018 16:28:39</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">5,599,976</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">dijm</a></td></tr>
  <tr onclick="changeHighlight( 'eid1' )" id="eid1" class="queryunshaded">
    <td nowrap=""><a onclick="javascript:window.open('IWViewer.jsp?id=3.6443276.6443276');" title="Open Image" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Image" border="0" alt="Open Image" src="URL.gif"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('URL;id=3.6443276.6443276','_newtab');" title="Open Workitem" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Workitem" border="0" alt="Open Workitem" src="URL.gif"></a>
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">67890</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">25/06/2019 11:01:01</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">09/07/2019 10:32:32</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">6,443,276</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank"></a></td></tr>
  <tr onclick="changeHighlight( 'eid2' )" id="eid2" class="queryshaded">
    <td nowrap=""><a onclick="javascript:window.open('IWViewer.jsp?id=3.6443287.6443287');" title="Open Image" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Image" border="0" alt="Open Image" src="URL.gif"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('URL;id=3.6443287.6443287','_newtab');" title="Open Workitem" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Workitem" border="0" alt="Open Workitem" src="URL.gif"></a>
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">23456</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">25/06/2019 11:01:24</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">09/07/2019 10:35:30</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">6,443,287</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank"></a></td></tr>
  <tr onclick="changeHighlight( 'eid3' )" id="eid3" class="queryunshaded">
    <td nowrap=""><a onclick="javascript:window.open('IWViewer.jsp?id=3.6443339.6443339');" title="Open Image" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Image" border="0" alt="Open Image" src="URL.gif"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('URL;id=3.6443339.6443339','_newtab');" title="Open Workitem" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Workitem" border="0" alt="Open Workitem" src="URL.gif"></a>
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">78901</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">25/06/2019 11:06:02</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">09/07/2019 10:40:39</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">6,443,339</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank"></a></td></tr>
  <tr onclick="changeHighlight( 'eid4' )" id="eid4" class="queryshaded">
    <td nowrap=""><a onclick="javascript:window.open('IWViewer.jsp?id=3.6443344.6443344');" title="Open Image" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Image" border="0" alt="Open Image" src="URL.gif"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:window.open('URL;id=3.6443344.6443344','_newtab');" title="Open Workitem" href="javascript:doNothing();"><img title="Open Workitem" border="0" alt="Open Workitem" src="URL.gif"></a>
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">34567</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">25/06/2019 11:06:17</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">09/07/2019 10:40:43</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">6,443,344</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank"></a></td></tr>
```

I have tried various solutions that look somewhat like this:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/other-software-applications/excel-and-web-browsers-help/131683-extracting-data-from-a-grid-on-webpage
and
[Scraping data from website using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066963/scraping-data-from-website-using-vba)

and trying to define the frames themselves to try and get the info from there?
(again: new to Excel VBA)

```
    'set myHTMLDoc to the main pages IE document
    Dim myHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLDoc = ie.Document

    'set myHTMLFrame2 as the 2nd frame of the main page (index starts at 0)
    Dim myHTMLFrame2 As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLFrame2 = myHTMLDoc.Frames(1).Document
```

With the above block of code I'm getting a "Run-time error '438'
Without the above block I'm getting a "Run-time error '1004'

The info I eventually want is in each row:

```
    </td><td scope="row" nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">67890</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">25/06/2019 11:01:01</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">09/07/2019 10:32:32</a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="URL" target="_Blank">6,443,276</a></td>
```

Ideally I'd like to dump each element into a cell

67890 | 25/06/2019 11:01:01 | 09/07/2019 10:32:32 | 6,443,276

There's 20 of these rows on each page (there's a button to press to get to the next page which I'll figure out later...hopefully haha)

Massive premptive Thank You to anyone who can help :)

-EDIT-
This is the code that I'm currently working with (not precious about it :P )

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim ie     As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objElementTR As Object
    Dim objTR  As Object
    Dim objElementsTD As Object
    Dim objTD  As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim intRow As Long
    Dim intCol As Long

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "URL"
    ie.Visible = True     ' loop until page is loaded
    Do Until (ie.ReadyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'set myHTMLDoc to the main pages IE document
    Dim myHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLDoc = ie.Document

    'set myHTMLFrame2 as the 2nd frame of the main page (index starts at 0)
    Dim myHTMLFrame2 As HTMLDocument
    Set myHTMLFrame2 = ie.Document.querySelector("[title=queue]").contentDocument.getElementById("oTable")

    result = myHTMLFrame2
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    myHTMLFrame2 = result
    Set objElementTR = html.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    ReDim myarray(0 To objElementTR.Length, 0 To 10)
    For Each objTR In objElementTR
        intRow = intRow + 1
        Set objElementsTD = objTR.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each objTD In objElementsTD
            myarray(intRow, intCol) = objTD.innerText
            intCol = intCol + 1
        Next objTD
        intCol = 0
    Next objTR
    With Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Resize(UBound(myarray), UBound(myarray, 2)).Value = myarray
    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: What's the url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try isolating the frame by its title attribute, then go via contentDocument and get the table by id

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title=queue]").contentDocument.querySelector("#oTable")
```

Then end `.querySelector("#oTable")` can be interchanged with `.getElementById("oTable")`

I would then dump the `.outerHTML` of the table [via clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674826/6241235) so as to paste table direct into sheet.

Comment: `ie.Document.querySelector("[title=queue]").contentDocument.querySelector("#oTable")` does not produce an error when I set Document Type to 11. I commented out `myHTMLFrame2 = result` and it runs until `.Resize(UBound(myarray), UBound(myarray, 2)).Value = myarray` before giving the Run-time error '1004', though it skips the whole For loop.

Comment: My code has selected your table. Did you see the other part of my answer? The link?

Comment: I did, and as it’s bedtime now I’ll try that tomorrow. Thank you so much for helping me out and being so prompt :)

Comment: No worries. Let me know if further questions. But yes, bedtime for today.